# monitor the most recently created folder with the specified name with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

There is a folder in which folders with fixed names are automatically created daily.
i want to monitor which is the latest folder and i made a vbscript for that but it doesn't work for some reason.
Folder names are automatically generated in DATA + date format, so I thought I would pay attention to the first character of "D" with the "instr" command and the last modified folder in an "if".

Here my code part of Function:

```
Function GetRecentFolder(path)
  Dim fso, folder
  
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set GetRecentFolder = Nothing
  For Each folder in fso.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
    If GetRecentFolder is Nothing  Then 
      Set GetRecentFolder = folder
   
    ElseIf instr (1,folder.Name, "D",1) and folder.DateLastModified > GetRecentFolder.DateLastModified Then
      Set GetRecentFolder = folder
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code...

Comment: When you set the return value for the first time, you don't check the name contains "D".  `If folder.Name like "DATA*" Then` might be a more-robust check here.

Comment: yes sorry, the error is to find the latest folder, but the folder name search does not work. the most recent folder is named METADATA, so you will always find it and not the DATA name.

Comment: @kovacsr instead of putting that in the comments [edit] the question and add the missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-arranging your tests so you exclude all folders which have the wrong name:

```vb
Function GetRecentFolder(path) As Object
    Dim fso, folder
  
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
    For Each folder in fso.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
        If folder.Name Like "DATA*" Then    
            If GetRecentFolder is Nothing  Then 
                Set GetRecentFolder = folder
            ElseIf folder.DateLastModified > GetRecentFolder.DateLastModified Then
                Set GetRecentFolder = folder
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This is working, Thank you for your help.